# Move existing item to the top of a listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I add items from an array into a ListView like below:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dataKeyList.Count; i++)
{
  CallTabLv.Items.Add(new { Label = " " + keyArray[i], Value = valueArray[i] });
}
```

If the `keyArray[i]` contains an item called `CustomerName`, how can I move it and its value to the top of the list ?

**Edit:**

Let say:

```
string[] arr1 = new string[] { "one", "two", "three" };
string[] arr2 = new string[] { "1", "2", "3" };

for (int i = 0; i < arr1.Length; i++)
{
  listView.Items.Add(new { C1 = arr1[i], C2 = arr2[i] });
}
```

Output:

```
Col    Col2
-----------
one     1
two     2
three   3
```

I want to move "three   3" to the top of the list, so it would be like:

```
Col    Col2
-----------
three   3
two     2
one     1
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try items.Insert Method?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding item, You can use `[Items.Insert][1]` to insert an item in particular position,It can be used To Change position of an existing item in `n`th index.

```
ListViewItem item= new ListViewItem("Test");//Define item here;
if(!CallTabLv.Items.Contains(theItem))
 {
    CallTabLv.Items.Insert(0,item);
 }
else
 {
   n = CallTabLv.Items.IndexOf(item);
   CallTabLv.Items.RemoveAt(n);
   CallTabLv.Items.Insert(0, item); 
 }
```

Comment: Hi @un-lucky, thanks for your solution, but how I know the index of my item since it is getting from array, the item will or will not be in the array..?